# Transform some codes from scala to Pyspark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and scala and I want to change the code that is written in scala to Pyspark code.
I dont know to  transform the where clause and `.withColumn("EVENT_YEAR",year('EVENT.cast("date")))` to pyspark and I am not the rest that I implemented is correct.

```
val df= df1.join(df2,Seq("PA_ID"))
.where('EVENT>='CONTINOUS_START && 'EVENT<= 'CONTINOUS_END) //>= and <= instead of > and <
.withColumn("EVENT",'EVENT.cast("date"))
.withColumn("EVENT_YEAR",year('EVENT.cast("date")))
.withColumn("AGE_AT_EVENT", 'EVENT_YEAR - 'BIRTH_YEAR)
.withColumn("LOOK_FORWARD", datediff('CONTINOUS_END,'EVENT_DATE))
.withColumn("LOOK_BACK", datediff('EVENT, 'CONTINOUS_START)
```

My try :

```
df = df1.join(df2,["PA_ID"])
.withColumn("EVENT",col("EVENT").cast("date"))
.withColumn('birth_year',year(col(EVENT))
.withColumn("AGE_AT_EVENT", 'EVENT_YEAR - 'BIRTH_YEAR)
.withColumn("LOOK_FORWARD", datediff('CONTINOUS_ENROL_END,'EVENT_DATE))
.withColumn("LOOK_FORWARD", datediff(col("CONTINOUS_END"),col("EVENT_DATE")))
.withColumn("LOOK_BACK", datediff(col("EVENT"),col("CONTINOUS_START")))
```

Comment: all of the functions used there can be directly used in pyspark (`pyspark.sql.functions`). just the `&&` will be updated to `and`. `where("col1>=filter1 and col2 <= filter2")`. -- what errors are you facing in your try?

Comment: keep [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html) handy!

Comment: You meant it will be like this? .where("EVENT>=CONTINOUS_START and EVENT <= CONTINOUS_END")

Comment: if `CONTINOUS_START` and `CONTINOUS_END` are columns, yes.

Comment: Or .where("EVENT_DATE">="CONTINOUS_ENROL_START" and "EVENT_DATE" <= "CONTINOUS_ENROL_END")
?

Comment: yes they Column

Comment: What do you think about this? .withColumn("AGE_AT_EVENT", 'EVENT_YEAR - 'BIRTH_YEAR)

Comment: you're subtracting two int columns -- use `func.col()` whenever you access a column. not required for expressions though (`expr`)